# Get Maximum String

Tags: powershell

How would I get the file with the maximum date?

```
BACKUP-20220114.BAK
BACKUP-20220118.BAK
BACKUP-20220120.BAK
```

How would I select the file with the largest date value?
I tried just finding the maximum string, but alas strings are not compared that way in powershell.

```
ls BACKUP* | select-object -Property Name | Measure-Object -Maximum
Measure-Object : Cannot compare "@{Name=BACKUP-20221028.bak}" because it is not IComparable.
```

How do I imbue the string with an `IComparable`?

Comment: Based on what you are showing, why not just sort descending and select the first one? (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment.

```
(
$BackUpDates = @'
BACKUP-20220114.BAK
BACKUP-20220118.BAK
BACKUP-20220120.BAK
'@  | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header BackupDetail
)

# Results
<#
BackupDetail       
------------       
BACKUP-20220114.BAK
BACKUP-20220118.BAK
BACKUP-20220120.BAK
#>

$BackUpDates | 
Sort-Object -Property BackupDetail -Descending
# Results
<#
BackupDetail       
------------       
BACKUP-20220120.BAK
BACKUP-20220118.BAK
BACKUP-20220114.BAK
#>


$BackUpDates | 
Sort-Object -Property BackupDetail -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1
# Results
<#
BackupDetail       
------------       
BACKUP-20220120.BAK
#>

Get-Content -path 'variable:\BackUpDates' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header BackUpDate | 
Sort-Object -Property BackUpDate -Descending |
Select-Object -First 1
# Results
<#
BackUpDate         
----------         
BACKUP-20220120.BAK
#>
```

If you insist on using `Measure-Command -Maximum`, then a similar approach is:

```
(
Get-Content -path 'variable:\BackUpDates' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header BackUpDate | 
Measure-Object -Property BackUpDate -Maximum
).Maximum
# Results
<#
BACKUP-20220120.BAK
#>
```